# Incorrect JSON Model in SwiftUI

Tags: json, swiftui

I am trying to retrieve the current news via API Call from the page https://newsapi.org. This has all worked well so far, but sometimes I can't retrieve certain values even though they are spelled correctly.
At the moment I am not able to retrieve the description and urlToImage. Thank you in advance....

This is my current code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Response: Codable {
   var articles: [Article]
}

struct Article: Codable {
   struct Source: Codable {
       var name: String
   }
   
   var source: Source
   
   var title: String
   // var description: String
   var url: URL
   //var urlToImage: URL
   var content: String
}

struct NewsGridView: View {
   @State private var articles = [Article]()
   
   var body: some View {
       
       ScrollView {
           
           
           
           
           // Generiert einen Button für jede Schlagzeile
           ForEach(articles, id: \.title) { item in
               
               ZStack {
                   
                   Rectangle()
                       .foregroundColor(Color(.systemGray6))
                       .cornerRadius(15)
                       .frame(width: 295, height: 350, alignment: .center)
                       .shadow(radius: 5)
                   
                   
                   VStack {
                       Text(item.title)
                           .foregroundColor(.black)
                           .fontWeight(.bold)
                           .frame(width: 260)
                           .padding(.horizontal, 25)
                       
                       
                   }
                   
               }
               
               
           }
       
       .task {
           await loadData()
       }
       
           
           
       }
       
       
   }
   func loadData() async {
       guard let url = URL(string: "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=de&apiKey=--API KEY--") else {
           print("Invalid URL")
           return
       }
       
       do {
           let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
           
           if let decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data) {
               articles = decodedResponse.articles
           }
           
       } catch {
           print("Error")
       }
   }
}
```

That’s what it prints when I add

```
print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))
```

```
Optional("{\"status\":\"ok\",\"totalResults\":34,\"articles\":[{\"source\":{\"id\":null,\"name\":\"tagesschau.de\"},\"author\":\"tagesschau\",\"title\":\"Krieg gegen die Ukraine: Berichte über weitere Massengräber bei Mariupol | tagesschau.de - tagesschau.de\",\"description\":\"Satellitenbildern zufolge soll es im Großraum Mariupol weitere Massengräber geben. Derweil wird ein neuer Fluchtkorridor aus der belagerten Hafenstadt vorbereitet, während sich russische Truppen im Osten des Landes festsetzen.\",\"url\":\"https://www.tagesschau.de/ausland/europa/ukraine-mariuopol-massengraeber-101.html\",\"urlToImage\":\"https://www.tagesschau.de/multimedia/bilder/mariupol-graeber-101~_v-original.jpg\",\"publishedAt\":\"2022-04-23T02:51:44Z\",\"content\":\"Satellitenbildern zufolge soll es im Großraum Mariupol weitere Massengräber geben. Derweil wird ein neuer Fluchtkorridor aus der belagerten Hafenstadt vorbereitet, während sich russische Truppen im O… [+5484 chars]\"},{\"source\":{\"id\":null,\"name\":\"Www.fr.de\"},\"author\":null,\"title\":\"Frankreich-Wahl: TV-Duell Macron – Le Pen - eine Umfrage zeigt klaren Sieger - fr.de\",\"description\":\"Vor der Frankreich-Wahl 2022 liefern sich Emmanuel Macron und Marine Le Pen in einem TV-Duell einen harten Schlagabtausch.\",\"url\":\"https://www.fr.de/politik/stichwahl-paris-frankreich-wahl-2022-macron-le-pen-tv-duell-news-tv-russland-91489350.html\",\"urlToImage\":\"https://www.fr.de/bilder/2022/04/20/91489350/28696175-emmanuel-macron-und-marine-le-pen-im-tv-duell-zur-frankreich-wahl-2022-1dfe.jpg\",\"publishedAt\":\"2022-04-23T02:49:00Z\",\"content\":\"<ol><li>Startseite</li><li>Politik</li></ol>Erstellt: 23.04.2022, 04:49 Uhr\\r\\nVon: Andreas Apetz\\r\\nKommentareTeilen\\r\\nVor der Frankreich-Wahl 2022 liefern sich Emmanuel Macron und Marine Le Pen in einem… [+9368 chars]\"},{\"source\":{\"id\":null,\"name\":\"N-tv.de\"},\"author\":\"n-tv NACHRICHTEN\",\"title\":\"Vermittlung im Ukraine-Krieg: UN-Generalsekretär besucht nach Moskau auch Kiew - n-tv NACHRICHTEN\",\"description\":\"Ehemalige hochrangige UN-Mitarbeiter erhöhen den Druck auf Generalsekretär Guterres: In einem Brief fordern sie ihn zu mehr Engagement auf, um an einer politischen Lösung im Ukraine-Krieg mitzuwirken. Nun wird bekannt, dass er die Hauptstädte beider Kriegspar…\",\"url\":\"https://www.n-tv.de/politik/UN-Generalsekretaer-besucht-nach-Moskau-auch-Kiew-article23284809.html\",\"urlToImage\":\"https://bilder3.n-tv.de/img/incoming/crop23284810/0221323798-cImg_16_9-w1200/283315222.jpg\",\"publishedAt\":\"2022-04-23T01:31:00Z\",\"content\":\"Ehemalige hochrangige UN-Mitarbeiter erhöhen den Druck auf Generalsekretär Guterres: In einem Brief fordern sie ihn zu mehr Engagement auf, um an einer politischen Lösung im Ukraine-Krieg mitzuwirken… [+1887 chars]\"},{\"source\":{\"id\":null,\"name\":\"News.de\"},\"author\":\"roj/news.de\",\"title\":\"Erdnahe Asteroiden heute: Potenziell gefährlich! DIESE Asteroiden nähern sich der Erde - m.news.de\",\"description\":\"Mit \\\"(2001 XP31)\\\" und \\\"(2015 BK515)\\\" erreichen heute - neben 9 weiteren Asteroiden - 2 potenziell gefährliche Asteroiden den erdnächsten Punkt auf ihrer Umlaufbahn. Ein Überblick über die aktuell größten Asteroiden in Erdnähe und potenzielle Gefahren.\",\"url\":\"https://www.news.de/panorama/856160169/asteroid-heute-am-23-04-2022-in-erdnaehe-nasa-liste-potenziell-gefaehrlicher-asteroiden-mit-groesse-und-entfernung-zur-erde-aktuell/1/\",\"urlToImage\":\"https://media.news.de/resources/thumbs/52/e6/857718024_736x414/welche-asteroiden-sind-heute-in-erdnaehe-1646312378.jpg\",\"publishedAt\":\"2022-04-23T00:30:24Z\",\"content\":\"Mit \\\"(2001 XP31)\\\" und \\\"(2015 BK515)\\\" erreichen heute - neben 9 weiteren Asteroiden - 2 potenziell gefährliche Asteroiden den erdnächsten Punkt auf ihrer Umlaufbahn. Ein Überblick über die aktuell grö… [+6164 chars]\"},{\"source\":{\"id\":\"spiegel-online\",\"name\":\"Spiegel Online\"},\"author\":\"DER SPIEGEL\",\"title\":\"»Irrsinniger Krieg«: Tinkoff-Bank will sich nach Putin-Kritik ihres Gründers umbenennen - DER SPIEGEL\",\"description\":\"Die russische Tinkoff-Bank wird bald anders heißen. Der neue Name ist vermutlich eine Reaktion auf die deutlichen Worte, des Firmengründers Oleg Tinkow – er hatte das »Massaker« in der Ukraine angeprangert.\",\"url\":\"https://www.spiegel.de/wirtschaft/unternehmen/russland-ukraine-krieg-tinkoff-bank-will-sich-nach-kritik-von-oleg-tinkow-an-wladimir-putin-umbenennen-a-5cedb88f-20cf-4afe-8737-a7c07090ee5d\",\"urlToImage\":\"https://cdn.prod.www.spiegel.de/images/d22b0560-69af-4f64-8025-ee0c9bc043e7_w1280_r1.77_fpx61_fpy50.jpg\",\"publishedAt\":\"2022-04-22T23:28:34Z\",\"content\":\"Nach der scharfen Kritik des Bankiers Oleg Tinkow am Ukrainekrieg hat sein Finanzinstitut, die Tinkoff-Bank, eine Umbenennung bekannt gegeben. »Das Unternehmen hat sich lange auf den Schritt vorberei… [+1607 chars]\"},{\"source\":{\"id\":null,\"name\":\"BUNTE.de\"},\"author\":\"Anja Wöhrer\",\"title\":\"Herzogin Kate & Prinz William: Zauberhafte Geburtstagsaufnahmen: Louis wird 4! - BUNTE.de\",\"description\":\"Der jüngste Sohn der Cambridges wird vier Jahre alt. Mit neuen, zuckersüßen Fotos von Prinz Louis bezaubern uns Herzogin Kate und Prinz William.\",\"url\":\"https://www.bunte.de/royals/britisches-koenigshaus/herzogin-kate-prinz-william-zauberhafte-geburtstagsaufnahmen-louis-wird-4.html\",\"urlToImage\":\"https://images.bstatic.de/47tQlSeaxunqcv1Dz1ru868R1Ok=/1200x630/filters:focal(391x388:411x408)/images/f2da2f5e/6197/436f/86b2/656c17fd88c3.jpg\",\"publishedAt\":\"2022-04-22T22:27:40Z\",\"content\":\"Zwei Tage nachdem Queen Elizabeth II. (96) ihren 96. Geburtstag feierte, ist nun ihr Urenkel Prinz Louis (4) an der Reihe. Am Samstag (23. April) wird der jüngste Sprössling von Prinz William (39) un… [+496 chars]\"},{\"source\":{\"id\":null,\"name\":\"N-tv.de\"},\"author\":\"n-tv NACHRICHTEN\",\"title\":\"Wilder Playoff-Showdown: Eisbären rupfen die Adler in neun Minuten - n-tv NACHRICHTEN\",\"description\":\"Die Favoriten auf die deutsche Eishockeymeisterschaft haben sich in ihren Playoff-Halbfinals trotz Rückstanden erneut durchgesetzt. Am Sonntag kann bereits eine Entscheidung fallen.\",\"url\":\"https://www.n-tv.de/sport/Eisbaeren-rupfen-die-Adler-in-neun-Minuten-article23284736.html\",\"urlToImage\":\"https://bilder2.n-tv.de/img/incoming/crop23284733/1501323191-cImg_16_9-w1200/0810e799ff5d25710b4c2dafa7320f50.jpg\",\"publishedAt\":\"2022-04-22T21:02:30Z\",\"content\":\"Die Favoriten auf die deutsche Eishockeymeisterschaft haben sich in ihren Playoff-Halbfinals trotz Rückstanden erneut durchgesetzt. Am Sonntag kann bereits eine Entscheidung fallen.\\r\\nMeister Eisbären… [+2624 chars]\"},{\"source\":{\"id\":null,\"name\":\"Www.ndr.de\"},\"author\":\"Florian Neuhauss\",\"title\":\"FC Barcelona nimmt die VfL-Frauen vor Rekordkulisse auseinander - NDR.de\",\"description\":\"Es hätte der Abend ihres Lebens als Fußballerinnen werden sollen - vor der Rekordkulisse von 91.648 Zuschauern im Halbfinal-Hinspiel der Champions League beim FC Barcelona erlebten die Spielerinnen des VfL Wolfsburg allerdings ein Debakel. Mit dem 1:5 (0:4) w…\",\"url\":\"https://www.ndr.de/sport/fussball/FC-Barcelona-nimmt-vor-Rekordkulisse-die-VfL-Frauen-auseinander,wolfsburg17760.html\",\"urlToImage\":\"https://www.ndr.de/sport/fussball/wolfsburg17762_v-contentxl.jpg\",\"publishedAt\":\"2022-04-22T20:30:49Z\",\"content\":\"Stand: 22.04.2022 22:21 Uhr\\r\\nEs hätte der Abend ihres Lebens als Fußballerinnen werden sollen - vor der Rekordkulisse von 91.648 Zuschauern im Halbfinal-Hinspiel der Champions League beim FC Barcelon… [+4647 chars]\"},{\"source\":{\"id\":\"spiegel-online\",\"name\":\"Spiegel Online\"},\"author\":\"DER SPIEGEL\",\"title\":\"Fußball-Bundesliga: Kruse-Dreierpack sorgt für Wolfsburger Glücksgefühle - DER SPIEGEL\",\"description\":\"Allein für diesen Abend hat sich der Winter-Transfer von Max Kruse nach Wolfsburg schon gelohnt. Gegen Mainz 05 traf er dreimal – und bringt den VfL damit dem Klassenerhalt ein ganzes Stück näher.\",\"url\":\"https://www.spiegel.de/sport/fussball/vfl-wolfsburg-besiegt-mainz-05-vor-allem-dank-max-kruse-a-c6083ce2-5aa2-433b-bda6-2ef9a3ce22a5\",\"urlToImage\":\"https://cdn.prod.www.spiegel.de/images/9139e7a4-81c2-455a-908b-cd268792b31b_w1280_r1.77_fpx62_fpy14.jpg\",\"publishedAt\":\"2022-04-22T20:27:07Z\",\"content\":\"Angeführt von Dreifachtorschütze Max Kruse hat ein wie entfesselnd aufspielende VfL Wolfsburg den vorentscheidenden Schritt zum Klassenerhalt in der Fußball-Bundesliga gemacht. Die Niedersachsen ließ… [+2011 chars]\"},{\"source\":{\"id\":null,\"name\":\"merkur.de\"},\"author\":null,\"title\":\"Ukraine-News: Russland räumt erstmals „Moskwa“-Verluste ein - Ausländische Kämpfer in Stahlwerk eingeschlossen - Merkur.de\",\"description\":\"Selenskyj sagt, Mariupol widersetze sich weiter Russland. Ein Pro-Kreml-Kanal veröffentlichte kurzeitig neue Todeszahlen der russischen Seite. News-Ticker.\",\"url\":\"https://www.merkur.de/politik/kiew-grossoffensive-ukraine-krieg-russland-news-aktuell-mariupol-putin-selenskyj-angriffe-zr-91491144.html\",\"urlToImage\":\"https://www.merkur.de/bilder/2022/04/21/91491144/28676040-das-russische-flaggschiff-moskwa-soll-durch-ukrainischen-beschuss-zerstoert-worden-sein-nun-wirft-die-ukraine-russland-einen-vergeltungsversuch-vor-1YzFroI9LTfe.jpg\",\"publishedAt\":\"2022-04-22T19:41:44Z\",\"content\":\"<ol><li>Startseite</li><li>Politik</li></ol>Erstellt: 23.04.2022, 04:50 Uhr\\r\\nVon: Richard Strobl, Patrick Mayer, Katharina Haase, Stephanie Munk, Christoph Gschoßmann, Fabian Müller\\r\\nKommentareTeilen… [+25691 chars]\"},{\"source\":{\"id\":null,\"name\":\"STERN.de\"},\"author\":\"STERN.de\",\"title\":\"Olaf Scholz verteidigt Waffen-Strategie: \\\"Es darf keinen Atomkrieg geben\\\" - STERN.de\",\"description\":\"Viele Länder liefern schwere Waffen an die Ukraine. Bundeskanzler Olaf Scholz bleibt aber zurückhaltend. In einem Interview lässt er durchblicken, was dah...\",\"url\":\"https://www.stern.de/politik/deutschland/olaf-scholz-verteidigt-waffen-strategie---es-darf-keinen-atomkrieg-geben--31799924.html\",\"urlToImage\":\"https://image.stern.de/31799964/t/wx/v2/w1440/r1.7778/-/olaf-scholz.jpg\",\"publishedAt\":\"2022-04-22T17:41:00Z\",\"content\":\"22.04.2022, 19:41 Uhr\\r\\n 3 Min. Lesezeit\\r\\nFrankreich, Tschechien, die Niederlande und sogar das kleine Estland: Alle liefern sie schwere Waffen. Olaf Scholz ist weiter zurückhaltend. In einem Intervie… [+5426 chars]\"},{\"source\":{\"id\":null,\"name\":\"SPORT1\"},\"author\":\"SPORT1\",\"title\":\"Formel 1 Qualifying LIVE: Verstappen holt Pole für Sprint-Rennen! F1 Heute im TV, Stream, Ticker - SPORT1\",\"description\":\"Ferrari geht auf seiner Hausstrecke in Imola als Favorit ins Wochenende. Aber nicht nur ein Crash von Carlos Sainz dämpft die Stimmung. Auch Charles Leclerc wird übertrumpft.\",\"url\":\"https://www.sport1.de/news/motorsport/formel1/2022/04/formel-1-qualifying-in-imola-live-startzeit-ubertragung-im-tv-stream-ticker\",\"urlToImage\":\"https://reshape.sport1.de/c/t/da4cf21c-5f70-4027-b661-13b35593be61/1200x630\",\"publishedAt\":\"2022-04-22T17:31:42Z\",\"content\":\"Heimspiel für Ferrari beim Großen Preis der Emilia-Romagna!\\r\\nAuf der ersten Europa-Station in dieser Formel-1-Saison geht es ins Autodromo Enzo e Dino Ferrari in Imola - nicht nur auf die italienisch… [+3476 chars]\"},{\"source\":{\"id\":null,\"name\":\"YouTube\"},\"author\":null,\"title\":\"LIVE : Der Countdown zu Show 8 | Let\'s Dance - RTL\",\"description\":\"Alle News und Infos zu Let\'s Dance: https://www.rtl.de/cms/sendungen/lets-dance.html?utm_source=youtube&utm_medium=editorial&utm_campaign=beschreibung&utm_te...\",\"url\":\"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fdVGuYKWUBA\",\"urlToImage\":\"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/fdVGuYKWUBA/hqdefault.jpg\",\"publishedAt\":\"2022-04-22T17:12:38Z\",\"content\":null},{\"source\":{\"id\":null,\"name\":\"Www.ndr.de\"},\"author\":null,\"title\":\"Corona-News-Ticker: Gericht kippt Hotspot-Regelung für MV - NDR.de\",\"description\":\"Die Voraussetzungen hätten laut Gericht für die Kommunen einzeln überprüft werden müssen. Mehr Corona-News im Live-Ticker.\",\"url\":\"https://www.ndr.de/nachrichten/info/Corona-News-Ticker-Gericht-kippt-Hotspot-Regelung-fuer-MV,coronaliveticker1716.html\",\"urlToImage\":\"https://www.ndr.de/nachrichten/info/hotspot142_v-contentxl.jpg\",\"publishedAt\":\"2022-04-22T16:38:20Z\",\"content\":\"Stand: 22.04.2022 20:08 Uhr\\r\\nIm Live-Ticker informiert NDR.de Sie auch heute - am Freitag, 22. April 2022 - aktuell über die Folgen der Coronavirus-Pandemie für Niedersachsen, Schleswig-Holstein, Mec… [+21739 chars]\"},{\"source\":{\"id\":null,\"name\":\"Www.br.de\"},\"author\":\"BR24 Redaktion\",\"title\":\"Ukraine: Russland nennt erstmals konkrete Kriegsziele - br.de\",\"description\":\"Russland will neben dem Donbass auch die gesamte Schwarzmeerküste einnehmen. Unterdessen mehren sich die Hinweise auf zahlreiche Kriegsverbrechen im Krieg gegen die Ukraine. Die deutsche Wirtschaft leidet laut Bundesbank erheblich unter dem Krieg.\",\"url\":\"https://www.br.de/nachrichten/deutschland-welt/ukraine-russland-nennt-erstmals-konkrete-kriegsziele,T3kQ5Ak\",\"urlToImage\":\"https://img.br.de/9fe982aa-7dba-443e-94d0-ca6c9cf9c83c.jpeg?q=80&rect=2,280,3998,2252&w=1600&h=900\",\"publishedAt\":\"2022-04-22T16:37:41Z\",\"content\":\"In der Ukraine wird während der orthodoxen Osterfeiertage weiter gekämpft. Nach Angaben des ukrainischen Präsidenten Wolodymyr Selenskyj hat Russland den Vorschlag einer Feuerpause über die Osterfeie… [+4719 chars]\"},{\"source\":{\"id\":null,\"name\":\"t-online.de\"},\"author\":\"Nora Schiemann, Nicolas Lindken\",\"title\":\"Körpersprache-Experte über Putins Auftritt: \\\"Der schläft seit Wochen schlecht\\\" - t-online\",\"description\":\"Russische Truppen kontrollieren offenbar Mariupol, der Kreml zeigt Putins Befehl an seinen Minister. Details am Präsidenten sorgen für Spekulationen.\",\"url\":\"https://www.t-online.de/nachrichten/ausland/id_92058550/koerpersprache-experte-ueber-putins-auftritt-der-schlaeft-seit-wochen-schlecht-.html\",\"urlToImage\":\"https://bilder.t-online.de/b/92/05/90/32/id_92059032/tid_da/index.png\",\"publishedAt\":\"2022-04-22T16:34:00Z\",\"content\":\"Russische Truppen kontrollieren offenbar Mariupol, der Kreml zeigt daraufhin einen Befehl Putins. Auffällige Details sorgen jetzt für Spekulationen. Ein Experte bewertet die skurrile Szene  im Video.… [+1045 chars]\"},{\"source\":{\"id\":null,\"name\":\"Jpgames.de\"},\"author\":\"Tony\",\"title\":\"Der Starttermin für das neue PlayStation Plus in Europa steht jetzt konkret fest • JPGAMES.DE - jpgames.de\",\"description\":\"Sony PlayStation hat den Start des neuen PlayStation Plus konkretisiert. Wir in Europa sind demnach als Letzte an der Reihe.\",\"url\":\"https://jpgames.de/2022/04/der-starttermin-fuer-das-neue-playstation-plus-in-europa-steht-jetzt-konkret-fest/\",\"urlToImage\":\"https://jpgames.de/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/God-of-War_2018_01-23-18_006.jpg\",\"publishedAt\":\"2022-04-22T16:28:30Z\",\"content\":\"Sony PlayStation hat den Start des neuen PlayStation Plus konkretisiert. Wir in Europa sind demnach als Letzte an der Reihe. Wie geplant beginnt das Programm in Asien (ohne Japan), wo am 23. Mai der … [+1075 chars]\"},{\"source\":{\"id\":null,\"name\":\"tagesschau.de\"},\"author\":\"tagesschau\",\"title\":\"Hohe Lebensmittelpreise: Streit über die Mehrwertsteuer | tagesschau.de - tagesschau.de\",\"description\":\"Wegen der stark steigenden Lebensmittelpreise sind Forderungen laut geworden, die Mehrwertsteuer bei Grundnahrungsmitteln auszusetzen. Wie sind die Reaktionen aus der Politik? Und was sagen Wirtschaftsexperten dazu?\",\"url\":\"https://www.tagesschau.de/wirtschaft/verbraucher/senkung-mehrwertsteuer-grundnahrungsmittel-101.html\",\"urlToImage\":\"https://www.tagesschau.de/multimedia/bilder/mehrwertsteuer-119~_v-original.jpg\",\"publishedAt\":\"2022-04-22T15:39:35Z\",\"content\":\"Wegen der stark steigenden Lebensmittelpreise sind Forderungen laut geworden, die Mehrwertsteuer bei Grundnahrungsmitteln auszusetzen. Wie sind die Reaktionen aus der Politik? Und was sagen Wirtschaf… [+5685 chars]\"},{\"source\":{\"id\":null,\"name\":\"play3.de\"},\"author\":\"Dennis Leschnikowski\",\"title\":\"The House Of The Dead Remake: PlayStation Move-Unterstützung wird nachgereicht - play3.de\",\"description\":\"In dieser Woche wurde das Remake zum düsteren Shooter \\\"The House of the Dead\\\" auch offiziell für die PlayStation 4 und weitere Plattformen angekündigt. Da es sich bei \\\"The House of the Dead\\\"\",\"url\":\"https://www.play3.de/2022/04/22/the-house-of-the-dead-remake-playstation-move-unterstuetzung-wird-nachgereicht/\",\"urlToImage\":\"https://www.play3.de/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/The-House-of-the-Dead.webp\",\"publishedAt\":\"2022-04-22T15:11:00Z\",\"content\":\"In dieser Woche wurde das Remake zum düsteren Shooter „The House of the Dead“ auch offiziell für die PlayStation 4 und weitere Plattformen angekündigt.\\r\\nDa es sich bei „The House of the Dead“ um eine… [+1880 chars]\"},{\"source\":{\"id\":null,\"name\":\"Www.zdf.de\"},\"author\":\"Zweites Deutsches Fernsehen\",\"title\":\"Russischer General äußert sich: Kriegsziel ist völlige Kontrolle über Donbass - zdf.de\",\"description\":\"Ein russischer General hat detaillierte Angaben zu Kriegszielen gemacht. Russland strebe unter anderem die vollständige Kontrolle über den gesamten Donbass und Süden des Landes an.\",\"url\":\"https://www.zdf.de/nachrichten/politik/kriegsziele-russland-ukraine-moldau-100.html\",\"urlToImage\":\"https://www.zdf.de/assets/mariupol-ukraine-100~1280x720?cb=1650639169708\",\"publishedAt\":\"2022-04-22T15:06:03Z\",\"content\":null}]}")
```

Comment: Use `do/try/catch` instead of `try` so that you can `print(error)` and see what the issue is. Also, you can try pasting your JSON into app.quicktype.io and seeing how the models differ from yours. Without seeing you actual JSON, no one here can give you a definitive answer.

Comment: to track down your issue, 
add `print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))` just after `let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)` 
and show us exactly what it prints.

Comment: if `description` and `urlToImage` can be missing (or null) from the data, then mark them as optional in your`Article` model.
Like this:
`var description: String?` and 
`var urlToImage: String?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this `Article` model, works for me with the data you have provided.

```
struct Article: Codable {
   struct Source: Codable {
       var name: String
   }
   
   var source: Source
   
   var title: String
   var description: String
   var url: URL
   var urlToImage: URL
   var content: String?  // <-- here optional
}
```

You can see this at the end of the data:  `\"content\":null`

Comment: you can try this approach: `ForEach(articles, id: \.title) { item in
            Text(item.content ?? "no content") 
        }`.